# How to print a text value on Kivy Screen

Tags: python, kivy

I have a variable `result = "some text"` and I want to use the value of this variable to print it on the Kivy Screen through a Label

I have tried 
.py

```
class ScreenThree(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenThree, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        result = "some text"
```

.kv

```
Label:
                    id: result_label
                    text: root.result
```

but as soon as i run the app, it stops immediately with an error for line `text: root.result`
I have no idea how to print values on screen in kivy because I have recently started learning kivy.

Please let me know what I can do to print whatever is in the `result` variable on the screen

Comment: Please post a [mcve]..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
class ScreenThree(Screen):
    result = StringProperty("some text")
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenThree, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: It worked, but what if I have to pass a variable to it from another class

Comment: And please provide same example what you want to do.

Comment: @Kiran_t what do you mean by "pass variable to it from another class"?